# Need help expanding this negative binomial expanison

Tags: binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

I am an A level Student studying for my papers and this is a question from a past paper...the original equation is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}$$
which part a says to convert to the following equation and than says to expand it till x^2 
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{2x}$$
need to expand this equation till x^2 and have been doing for a long time but cant ..need to do it quick...thank you for the help

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_(mathematics)#Dealing_with_more_square_roots or $$x=\cos2t$$

Comment: what do u mean...sorry but i dont understand..how is this expansion?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Do you know how to expand $\sqrt{1+x}$ into a Taylor polynomial? How about $\sqrt{1-x}$? And where is this problem coming from? And why are you in such a hurry?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Did you want $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\dfrac12x-\dfrac18x^2...$?

Comment: I am an A level Student studying for my papers and this is a question from a past paper...the original equation is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}$$ which part a says to convert to the above equation and than says to expand it till x^2

Comment: Why do you want to expand ? To find the limit?

Comment: i am in a hurry because i have a paper very soon relating to this and want to understand this as soon as possible :)

Comment: uhmm can we add pictures?if yes i will send a screenshot of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the binomial expansion, $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\dfrac12x-\dfrac18x^2+\dfrac1{16}x^3+o(x^4)$$ and $$\sqrt{1-x}=1-\dfrac12x-\dfrac18x^2-\dfrac1{16}x^3+o(x^4)$$ so $$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{2x}=\dfrac{x+\dfrac18x^3+o(x^4)}{2x}=\dfrac12+\dfrac1{16}x^2+o(x^3).$$

Comment: thank you very much my friend you have saved my paper:)

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck with the paper!